# C# multi-threaded console application - Console quits before threads complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a c# console application that creates up to 5 threads.

The threads are executing fine, but the UI thread shuts down as it finishes its work.

Is there a way to keep the main UI thread running, for as long as the side threads are running?

```
foreach (var url in urls)
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting thread: " + url); 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(myMethod), url);
}
```

I'm kicking off my threads as per the code above.

Comment: What if you created normal threads, instead of using the threadpool?

Comment: What version of .NET?  If .NET 4.0 I'd recommend TPL tasks, store all the tasks in an array, and use Tasks.WaitAll(myTaskArray) before exiting.

Comment: I think the threads need to be `BackgroundWorker=false`

Comment: @James should have posted that as an answer, and great work on the blog btw :)

Answer (score 9):

The threads in the ThreadPool are background threads and that means an exiting application won't wait for them to complete.

You have a few options:

- wait with for example a semaphore
- wait on a counter with Sleep() , very crude but OK for a simple console app.
- use the TPL, `Parallel.ForEach(urls, url => MyMethod(url));`

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't recommend the Counter + Sleep at all.. it's also worth to note that one can use a `CountDownEvent`.

Comment: @Lirik The CountDownEv is Fx4+, then you might as well use TPL.

Comment: @Henk, There is a certain amount of overhead with TPL and if the tasks are very short, then TPL is not as efficient. In those cases it's much better to use a `ThreadPool` or just have a few dedicated consumer threads that process the tasks. You can use a `CountDownEvent` in both cases, or just call `Join` on the threads...

Comment: @lirik : The OP is processing URLs, I'm pretty sure a Task is affordable.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using .NET 4.0:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(var url in urls)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(myMethod, url));
}

// do other stuff...

// On shutdown, give yourself X number of seconds to wait for them to complete...
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah - the ThreadPool is background. It is queued, but then your program ends. Finished. Program terminates.

Read up on Semaphores (WaitSignal) and wait- The threads in the callback at the end signal they are ended, when all have signaled that the main thread can continue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .net 4 then:

```
urls.AsParallel().ForAll(MyMethod);
```

Prior to .net 4 then start individual threads, keep them in a list and call Join(). The fact  the workers are not background would keep them alive after the main thread exited, but the Join() is more explicit.

```
        List<Thread> workers = new List<Thread>();
        foreach(var url in urls)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(MyMethod) {IsBackground = false};
            workers.Add(t);
            t.Start(url);
        }

        foreach (var worker in workers)
        {
            worker.Join();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest hack to fix your problem.

In your program class:

```
static volatile int ThreadsComplete = 0;
```

In your "myMethod" at the end before return:

```
//ThreadsComplete++; //*edit* for safety's sake
Interlocked.Increment(ref ThreadsComplete);
```

In your main method before it returns/ends:

```
while(ThreadsComplete < urls.Count) { Thread.Sleep(10); }
```

The above essentially hacks together a WaitForAll synchronization method.

Comment: That's why you have a `CountdownEvent`... there is no need for looping or sleeping, which is bad practice for waiting anyway.

Comment: @Henk Holterman & Lirik, wouldn't you agree that "bad practice" is a little more subjective than "wrong answer". This answer was stated as a hack, the OP approved of it. So, I don't see what point your trying to make. Also, CountDownEvent is a fairly new addition to .Net and in this specific case would be more programming overhead then just using a Parallel ForEach. So, in THIS case CountdownEvent would not be a 'best practice' either right?

Answer (score -1):

in Main:

```
var m = new ManualResetEvent(false);
// do something
foreach (var url in urls)
{
  Console.WriteLine("starting thread: " + url); 
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(myMethod), url);
}
m.WaitOne();


private static void myMethod(object obj)
{
  try{
   // do smt
  }
  finally {
    m.Set();
  }
}
```

Comment: If he changes the `ManualResetEvent` to a `CountDownEvent` then this is going to be a pretty good solution.

Comment: @Lirik With enough changes, it could write a poem also

Comment: yes of course CountDownEvent is a true thing. never underestimate it!